# TypeError when cell contains double figures

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below is working how I want it too except when cell A1 is large then 9.  As soon as I enter anything greater like 10 or 11, I get the error

"TypeError: theSplitString.split is not a function"

What am I doing wrong?

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quote List');
  var copyViewQuote = ss.getSheetByName('New Job');
  var quoteNuber = copyViewQuote.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(+quoteNuber)
  var theSplitString = ssSheet.getRange("M" + quoteNuber).getValue(); // WHICH PARTS STRING TO USE
  var thePartAmount = ssSheet.getRange("N" + quoteNuber).getValue(); // GIVES YOU THE NUMBER OF PARTS IN THE STRING
  var spiltstring = theSplitString.split(","); // WHAT SPILTS THE PARTS IN THE STRING
  var data = 1; // START FROM 1 AS 0 GIVES UNDEFINED AS FIRST PART OF STRING
var partListNumer = 1;

copyViewQuote.getRange('H5:L200').clearContent();

  for(row=5; row<=5+thePartAmount; row++){

    //if (partListNumer <= thePartAmount){
    //copyViewQuote.getRange(row, 8).setValue(partListNumer);
    //partListNumer = partListNumer + 1
    //}

    //each spiltstring array data is put on Column 6 or column F that starts from row 10 to 10 + length of the splitstring array
    copyViewQuote.getRange(row,9).setValue(spiltstring[data]);
    data++;
    copyViewQuote.getRange(row,10).setValue(spiltstring[data]);
    data++;
    copyViewQuote.getRange(row,11).setValue(spiltstring[data]); 
    data++;
    copyViewQuote.getRange(row,12).setValue(spiltstring[data]);
    data++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to split the value of the cell, which can only be done on strings.

Try this on your sheet:

[image]

This will force all call data to be strings, which you can work a split function on. That should fix the issue.